# SQL Server : inserting multi-table output from stored procedure into separate tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns several tables (currently consumed by a web service). I now need to insert that output into a SQL Server database.

I can insert a single table if I know the existing definition via

```
INSERT INTO #temp
    EXEC ('myProcSQlhere')
```

But for this I need to know the definition of the output table in advance.

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM OPENQUERY(SERVERNAME, 'EXEC myProcSQlhere')
```

Which gets around knowing the table definition, but only allows entry into one table. So how do I insert data into multiple tables?

Answer (score 3):

A stored procedure can only return one value. What your stored procedure does is performing multiple selects and so giving multiple result sets. This works for systems that can consume multiple result sets but you are stuck in SQL-Server.

Check if the stored proc doesn't already call independent stored procedures for each result set and if so, call those. Or use the definition of the stored procedure and call each query used within sequentially.

If you have no access to the system providing the stored procedure, you will need to implement a [CLR stored procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) and [fetch each result set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcd4d328.aspx) to store the results into different tables.

Comment: `This works for systems that can consume multiple result sets but you are stuck in SQL-Server.` ..which systems  ?

Comment: I currently interrogate the result set from vb.  The result set just has several tables in it.  It works really nicely from there.  The issue is I now need to do more with it in SQL, and have no idea how to access tables after 1.

Comment: That's the point of this answer, in Sql you can't get the next tables, only the first one.